# API Token: How do I gain access to the Sabre SOAP API?

Tags: sabre

I am the CEO of a travel metasearch engine and would like to gain access to the Sabre SOAP APIs so that my team of developers can integrate them into our software. How do I get a token and any other information I need to access the API?

Answer (score 2):

If you are a Sabre customer already, you can obtain further details contacting your account executive and also at Dev Studio (https://developer.sabre.com). If you wish to become a customer, you should check https://www.switchtosabre.com if you wish to become a customer. SOAP APIs are only available to Sabre customers and REST APIs can be tested by external agents without charge.